# npm run dev changes character set from uft-8 to ascii in laravel 5.4 vue component

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, laravel-5.3

I'm new to node.js and vue.js. I have a project in laravel 5.4 and I create vue component, when i run "npm run dev" all Persian or Latin the characters changes to "?" . how can this be solved?

Comment: What is the encoding of your source files?

Comment: my main blade is utf-8 <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: It's not relevant what you say in your meta tag, I asked for the editor encoding.

Comment: i don.t understand what your meaning

Comment: That's too sad, but I can't explain better.

Comment: i'm useing php storm and i've set all encoding to utf-8 , in the editor all things are fine but when i run "npm run dev" in cmd it is turnig non-english characters to "?"

Comment: Are you sure the font you're using supports unicode? Also, if Babel is invo,ved and you're set to transpile to ES5 this might be the cause: https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/#leanpub-auto-strings-and-regular-expressions